# Android error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android, so maybe this question is naive.

I am trying to build a layout with two lists side by side. It works fine when I have one list, but when I add a second one, I get this error.

My view extends Activity and not ListActivity.

But I just can't figure out why my build fails with this error:

```
\main.xml:13: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/selected_list').
\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:598: The following error occurred while executing this line:
\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:627: null returned: 1
```

This is what my main.xml looks like:

```
<ListView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>
    <ListView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@android:id/selected_list"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use "`@+id/list`" and "`@+id/selected_list`" instead of the "`@android:id/...`".

To find these id's in the code use:

```
findViewById(R.id.list);
```

or

```
findViewById(R.id.selected_list);
```

and make sure you import the R file: .R; and not com.android.R;

Comment: And the most important mention REALLY REALLY is to import the right R and not to have through some hickup having eclipse changed it to com.android.R - Marmor, thanks for pointing that out, stepping too often into that trap....

Answer (score 3):

change your id's of list view

code:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/selected_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
```